# Retornar o id gerado

Tags: angular, spring-data

estou usando Angular 6+ e springboot. Como gero um id e recupero ele?

ex:
tenho a seguinte page:
[image: Imagem da pagina]

Quando o usuário clickar em "Novo" vai fazer um post. E este id que foi gerado aparecerá no campo Código.

*Pensei em fazer uma consulta e pegar o ultimo id do banco, mas tenho receio que este tempo de processamento pegue o id gerado por outro usuário.

Comment: olá, você não expôs como está sua estrutura de back-end com o spring boot. Mas, ao persistir um elemento na banco é devolvido o elemento com o id criado caso seja auto increment ou gerado automaticamente. Recomendo retornar o objeto persistido no back ou mesmo só id. Realizar outra chamada de api para buscar o último id é inseguro e custoso.

Comment: É um post simples -》 repository.save(entity) onde entity contem todos as variáveis etc.

Comment: Comentei o caso de retornar a última id. Suponha que tenho 1000 usuários clicando no botão ao mesmo tempo. Vai dar conflito, não?

Comment: Esse controle é realizado no backend. Verifique a notation [@Transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) e seus parametros. Um em especial é o _Isolation_ >>Good coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca um (click) no button chamando o post, e no then você atribui o id buscado na variável que é seu ngModel na página HTML

.then(response => {
   response = response.json();
   this.id =  response.id;
 })

Coloca um loading enquanto vai no servidor e toda vez que acionar o novo e entrar no método para fazer o post sempre limpa o ID, pra não correr o risco de usar o anterior.